# Building a modular approach in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have the following code and it matches my requirements, however, it is not modular and not generic. For example, I might have a hundred of `stats` objects. Is there a way to make it more generic?

Actually, in `dataSeries` I have only two arrays of objects. And I am sorting them based on their color `(red, green)`. Therefore, there are only four `stats` objects initialized.

```
var stats1 = {data: []}
var stats2 = {data: []}
var stats3 = {data: []}
var stats4 = {data: []}


stats1.data.push(self.dataSeries[0].data.filter(function (x) { return x.color == "green" }))
stats2.data.push(self.dataSeries[0].data.filter(function (x) { return x.color == "red" }))
stats3.data.push(self.dataSeries[1].data.filter(function (x) { return x.color == "green" }))
stats4.data.push(self.dataSeries[1].data.filter(function (x) { return x.color == "red" }))

a=[{ data: stats1.data[0] }, { data: stats2.data[0] }, { data: stats3.data[0] }, { data: stats4.data[0] }];
```

Comment: migrate to codereview?

Comment: any ideas you might have already? any patterns in the code that can be "genericised" for example?

Comment: I am relatively new on this environment. That is why first I looked for functionality rather than making more generic or modular. Since I see similarity in my code, then I thought that should be a way to make it more modular.

Comment: @Knu Codereview is for real code. Hypothetical code or code that hasn't been created yet is off-topic there.

Comment: What is `self` here?

Comment: self.dataSeries comes froms somewhere else, that I am trying to sort these dataset based on their color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you know the number of data, you've got it all:

```
var numberOfData = 4;
var a = [];
for (var i = 0; i < numberOfData; i++) {
  var color = (i%2 === 0) ? 'green' : 'red';
  var index = Math.floor(i/2);
  var stat = {data: []};
  stat.data.push( self.dataSeries[index].data.filter(function (x) { return x.color == color }) );
  a.push( {data: stat.data[0] } );
}
```

Now it looks like you are creating a useless `stat.data` array, if so you could simplify the code by:

```
var numberOfData = 4;
var a = [];
for (var i = 0; i < numberOfData; i++) {
  var color = (i%2 === 0) ? 'green' : 'red';
  var index = Math.floor(i/2);
  var d = self.dataSeries[index].data.filter(function (x) { return x.color == color });
  a.push( {data: d} );
}
```

The resulting `a` array will be the same as in your example in both cases.

**UPDATE** If you have more colors, you could put them all in an array of `colors` and get the matching one using a modulo:

```
var numberOfData = 4;
var colors = ['green', 'red', 'blue', 'pink', 'rainbow'];

var a = [];
for (var i = 0; i < numberOfData; i++) {
  var color = colors[i%colors.length];
  var index = Math.floor(i/2);
  var d = self.dataSeries[index].data.filter(function (x) { return x.color == color });
  a.push( {data: d} );
}
```

Comment: @ilyasUyanik glad it helped you, I jave updated my answer with how to handle as many colors as you want in the third example.

Comment: Thanks a lot Floribon, it is very well written.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to clean this up would be to move all the variables into an array. Here's a sample of one possibility.

*Edit: added support for unknown number of colors*

```
var stats = [], colors = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    stats.push({data: []});
}

colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow"];
colorCount = colors.length;
for(var i = 0, len = stats.length; i < len; i++) {
    color = colors[i % colorCount];
    stats[i].data.push(self.dataSeries[0].data.filter(
        function (x) { return x.color == color }
    ));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Will, what if I have more than two colors? Let 's a say I have a array of color objects. 'color=['green', 'red', 'blue', 'yellow', etc]'

Comment: Would you just cycle through them, starting over after you get to the end?

Answer (score 1):

This may give you an idea of how to turn it into something more generic.

```
a=[{ data: stats1.data[0] }, { data: stats2.data[0] }, { data: stats3.data[0] }, { data: stats4.data[0] }];

pushColor = function(stats, pos, x, color) {
    stats.data.push(self.dataSeries[pos].data.filter(function (x) {
        return x.color === color;
    }))
}

var arrayLength = a.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    pushColor(a[i].data, a[1].pos, a[i].color, "green");
}
```

Comment: it is great answer. Thanks a lot alebruck, What if I have a more than two colors? Lets say 'color=['green', 'red', 'blue', 'yellow', etc]'

Comment: How do you want to interact with this array? iterate the loop through each color?

Comment: First data sorted based on color. I will have `color` array to sort the `dataSeries` object.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong.

Do you have an array with multiple objects.
Each object has a property called 'color'.
Do you want to order this array based on this property?

Comment: @alebruck you could generate even the initial `a` array in the loop, no need to write that big array manually.

Comment: You are correct @floribon, but I really don't think his question is about how to literally improve that code.
I really think the `a` array is just an example of how his input data is structured.